# React Flatlist - Trying to order item data

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flat list that renders an array of data. I'm trying to organise the data, so that each row is sorted out in such a fashion as this, though not strictly like this, I just want multiples rows per each item.

```
item1-date | item1-text1 |item1-text2
item1-text3 | item1-text4 |item1-text5
---------------------------------------
item2-date | item2-text1 |item2-text2
item2-text3 | item2-text4 |item2-text5
```

or to have the date appear on a new row by itself, like a header row per each item

```
item1-date
item1-text3 | item1-text4 |item1-text5
---------------------------------------
item2-date 
item2-text3 | item2-text4 |item2-text5
```

But I can't seem to get it to work with styles, using flexdirection etc. I even tried putting a new line in (see below), but that doesn't work. Any ideas, please?

```
           <View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <Text>
                  {item.Date} {"\n"} {"\n"} //tried doing this to make a new line
                </Text>
                <Text>{item.text1}<Text>
                <Text>{item.text2}<Text>
                <Text>{item.text3}<Text>                 
           </View>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<View>
  <Text>Date</Text>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <Text>1 | </Text>
    <Text>2 | </Text>
    <Text>3</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

So what is happening is that the first `<View />` tag is used to align elements vertically and then the next view will align then horizontally

Comment: That kinda works. But what if I want to create a grid of data, with say 6 cells, 3 on top of 3, for each item.

Comment: If you are using a FlatList, there is a numColumns prop that you can use to show views as grids https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. If I use NumColumns then it creates a new column for every item. I want to create columns within each item.

Comment: If you want two cols you can write another horizontal view like<View>
  <Text>Date</Text>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <Text>1 | </Text>
    <Text>2 | </Text>
    <Text>3</Text>
  </View><View style={{ flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <Text>1 | </Text>
    <Text>2 | </Text>
    <Text>3</Text>
  </View>
</View>